# textContent working but nodeValue does not

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, xml-parsing

To better understand the difference between **textConent** and **nodeValue** I'd like to find out why using nodeValue in my code is not working. I have the following XML string which gets loaded through AJAX via a jQuery callback. If you look at the center of the loop, that section will produce a null value if I use nodeValue in place of textContent.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Sensors>
        <Sensor>
            <id>56</id>
            <state>false</state>
        </Sensor>
    </Sensors>
```

I use this function below to parse the XML.

**JavaScript**

```
  function parseSensors(data,status,xhr) {
         var xml = xhr.responseXML;
         var sensors = xml.documentElement.childNodes;

         var list="<ul>";             
         for(var i=0; i < sensors.length; i++) {
             list= list +"<li>"+sensors[i].childNodes[0].textContent+"</li>";                 
         }
         list=list+"</u>";
         document.getElementById("real-time_active_sensors").innerHTML=list;            
     }
```

Comment: I had the same problem what Usman said is corrent:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23816032/need-help-in-parsing-this-xml-code-with-raw-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text portion of a node is actually a child of the node itself. If a node has no data in it, such as  then a call to childNodes[0].nodeValue will fail. You need to check for how many childNodes are actually present before you attempt to access them. Otherwise you'll need to enforce a protocol that demands that when XML data is created it cannot contain empty tags.